# Remove Browser history in Angular-Node-Passport Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, passport.js

I made an angular App, which is using Node and Passport for `Authentication(Google, Facebook)`.

Whenever a user clicks on the login button, the browser will call the `*/auth/google/*` node route, the Passport will open google consent form(history state1), and on successful/failure redirection, it will call `*/auth/google/callback*`(history state2). In the callback route, I am redirecting the user back to the main website.

But my problem is when the user presses the browser back button, it will again open the consent window.

Is there a way that will help in disabling these states from storing in the browser history from `node/passport` or with plain Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

try `replaceUrl: true` while triggering the navigation to main page

```
// Navigate to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Comment: Navigation is getting triggered by the node server, can't control it in the angular.